# Universal properties in Category theory

Tags: category-theory

> "A representable functor $F:C \rightarrow Set$ or $F:C^{op} \rightarrow Set$ encodes a
> **universal property** of its representing
> object. Put colloquially, a universal property of an object $X$ is a
> *description* of the covariant functor $Hom(X,-)$ or of the contravariant functor $Hom(-,X)$ associated to that object"

This paragraph is taken from Riehl, Category theory in context. I'm confused about the idea she is trying to express. How this encoding work intuitively? In what respect is a representable functor a **description** of a Hom-functor?

Comment: This is more informal than anytthing else. But the idea is that a universal property of $X$ corresponds to the assertion that under certainly circumstances you will have a unique map *from* $X$ (that is, information about $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$), or a unique map *to* $X$ (information about $\mathrm{Hom}(-,X)$). For example, the universal property of the product $P=\prod X_i$ tells you that the hom functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-,P)$ corresponds families of map into the $X_i$; i..e, $\mathrm{Hom}(-,P)\cong \prod \mathrm{Hom}(-,X_i)$.

Comment: "an element of a group $G$ 'is' a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to G$", so the forgetful functor from $\mathsf{Group}$ to $\mathsf{Set}$ *describes* homs from $\mathbb{Z}$ - is that something like what you're looking for?